# Dynamic change of html attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I have this jQuery plugin - Plax: https://github.com/cameronmcefee/plax

I wanted it to be responsive, which I partly have: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/

My problem is the html attributes:

```
<img src="/parallax/4.svg" data-xrange="20" data-yrange="10" id="plax-img4"/>
    <img src="/parallax/3.svg" data-xrange="5" data-yrange="40" id="plax-img3"/>
```

The problem is that the `data-xrange` and `data-yrange` isn't being responsive, and when you minimize the browser-window they have the same x-range and y-range no matter what size the window have. When minimized the ranges are to large.

So I must get size of window when it resize, then with an algorithm find xrange and yrange, and then, change the attributes with jquery and then reinitialize plaxify.

I was thinking somthing like this pseudo-code, but don't know how to do it so it works:

```
$('#my-element')
    .attr('data-xrange', 'New Value')
    .attr('data-yrange', 'New Value');

// You can dynamically redefine the range of a layer
// by running plaxify() on it again.
$('#my-element').plaxify();

$(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 320 && #my-element.is('New Value')) {
                    #my-element.removeAttr('data-xrange,data-yrange');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's from documentation of Plax:

```
$('#plax-octocat').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40})
$('#plax-earth').plaxify({"xRange":20,"yRange":20,"invert":true})

$('#plax-bg').plaxify({"xRange":10,"yRange":10,"invert":true})
$.plax.enable()

$('#my-btn').click(function(){
  // bigger range
  $('#plax-octocat').plaxify({"xRange":200,"yRange":200}) // LOOK HERE
})
```

As you can see, if you want new xrange and yrange, then you have to set it by yourself. Then your piece of code should look something like:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 320){
       $('#my-element').plaxify({"xRange":newValue,"yRange":newValue});
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Also after changing data attributes with `plaxify()` you have to set CSS top and left values to 0. Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/instead/4kRDL/14/

Comment: Hey @instead.... I tried your suggestion, but I can't seem to get it to work... In my fiddle you can see what I have done: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/2/

I would be cool if I could get this to work

Comment: Hey, I find out that if you want to change xrange and yrange values dynamicly, then you HAVE TO write them in javascript.  <br/>
I tried it on my localhost and you have to place in your code:  `$('#plax-img1').plaxify({"xRange":40,"yRange":40,"invert":true});
  $('#plax-img2').plaxify({"xRange":60,"yRange":40,"invert":true});
        $('#plax-img3').plaxify({"xRange":5,"yRange":40,"invert":false});
  $('#plax-img4').plaxify({"xRange":20,"yRange":10});`  And then your onresize event will work

Comment: I tried doing what you wrote, but this just made the effect stop working?

see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/3/

Comment: Sory, I should give you at first ready solution: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/5/    In your fiddle is missing the comma between yrange and invert

Comment: Okay, thank you now the effect is working;)

But it doesn't seem like the scaling is working properly?
Don't if it's just my browser?
Does it work on yours?

When moving the mouse the x-rang and y-range is still to big, and onscale doesn't seem to fit?

Comment: You can delete from HTML code the data-x-range and other data attributes, because you don't need them. As I said, setting dynamically x-range and y-range is possible, when you doing this in JavaScript. You can see it in the my fiddle, but I forgot to delete from HTML the data attributes. The attributes won't change when onresize event will be triggered BUT the change is "saved" in JavaScript. If you can't see any difference when browser window is small, then give for examle some big values like 200, and you will see IT WORKS. You have to testing now these values. Thats all.

Comment: okay, thank you.

I have just deleted the html, and when scaling down it works (i just think i need to adjust the css in the media queries).

But when you scale it back up it keeps the x-range and y-range from the the smaller range... is it possible to "delete" the settings when scaling back up to more the 480px?

Comment: Yes. You can do it in `else` statement and put in there the code which initiate default values. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/instead/YDvZH/

Comment: Thank you for that. it's getting better, but it still doesn't seem to work properly.

When scaling the x-range and y-range is still to large, and it seems as if some left-margin is added.

When scaling up again, the positions of the elements has changed, you can see it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kRDL/6/... Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well I've made a mistake and forgot to give value 0 to `small` variable. http://jsfiddle.net/instead/4kRDL/8/ Here is correct version (and without attributes in HTML which you don't need). Are you using Firebug when debugging? Because I think you don't... This tool will help you a lot. There is no margin-left added when scaling window or when moving a mouse. Only top and left css values are changed, because these images are positioned absolute

Comment: Is it working properly in your browsers?

I use Safari on mac and I can't seem to get it working, not even the fiddle you sent?
It still offsets the elements when scaling down the browser window, and when scaling back up, it keeps the values, from when it was scaled down.

No you are correct i don't use firebug. My preferred browser is safari and I didn't think firebug worked that good in here.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but i think this is working. In your first post you said, that you want change xrange and yrange and code, that I gave you is doing this

Comment: Ah... Sorry Man, I didn't test this to good. I thinh you need this: http://jsfiddle.net/instead/4kRDL/14/ I'll update my answer too

Comment: Arhhhh I think we got it here!!!!!!

This is fantastic, thank you so much for your time and effort.

It works great in safari, I will just test it in other browsers to.